# cpp operator overloading inside std::function

Tags: c++, types, operator-overloading

I create a `complex` struct in `complex.h` and overload a series of operators (including `^`) to work on the four operations `complex+double`, `double+double`, `complex+complex`, `double+complex`:

```
complex operator^(complex& lhs, complex& rhs){
    double new_mag = std::pow(mag(lhs), rhs.re);
    double new_arg = angle(lhs.re, lhs.im) * rhs.re;
    return complex(new_mag * std::cos(new_arg), new_mag * std::sin(new_arg)); 
}
```

I then define two structs in the file `calc.cpp` which includes `complex.h`, namely `op` and `func`:

```
struct op{
    char symbol;
    uint8_t precedence;
    uint8_t assoc;
    uint8_t type;

    std::function<complex (complex, complex)> operate;

};

struct func{
    std::string symbol;
    uint8_t type;

    std::function<complex (complex, complex)> operate;

};
```

Where each struct also defines a functional. I then attempt to initialize objects of these structs in the same file:

```
op op6{'^', 4, RIGHT, BINARY, [] (complex a, complex b){return b ^ a;}}; // no errors

// no operator "^" matches these operands -- operand types are: complex ^ complex
func f10{"sqrt", ONE_INPUT, [] (complex a, complex b){return a ^ complex(1/2);}};
```

I also tried leaving `complex(1/2)` just as the double `.5` but that gave me the same error, except with operand types `complex ^ double`.

My question is how can operator `^` not match operands of type `complex` when it is defined to do so, and DOES do so in the initialization of `op6`?

Comment: `complex (complex, complex)` does not match `complex operator^(complex& lhs, complex& rhs)`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Note that you probably want `complex operator^(const complex& lhs, complex& rhs)`. You don't modify `lhs` or `rhs`, and this will allow you to pass temporaries or things that implicitly convert to `complex` to your function.

Comment: Also, it should be `complex operator^(const complex& lhs, const complex& rhs)` to make it able to accept temporaries.

Comment: FYI, you can't overload the operators for `double+double`, since `double` is a fundamental type to the language and its operators are all built-in to the language. You can only overload operators for custom `struct`/`class` types, like `complex`

Comment: @S.M. are `complex a` and `complex b` passed into the std::func also temporaries, or can they be passed by reference?

Comment: @rjc810, first of all, they *should* be passed by reference to constant value. Next, even though `a` and `b` are "temporaries", that doesn't mean that doesn't mean that thay are r-values in the expressions like `b ^ a`. They are l-values in this context.

Comment: Be aware that you can't change an operator's precedence.  Your overload of `operator^` will have the same precedence as the default `operator^`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operator requires non-constant references:

```cpp
complex operator^(complex& lhs, complex& rhs);
```

In the expression `return a ^ complex(1/2)` the second operator is an r-value.
Try to define the operation using const references:

```cpp
complex operator^(complex const& lhs, complex const& rhs);
```